# Using graphicspath in latex/sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I have an Sweave file, where I need to embed a png and pdf from another folder. This is how I tried it

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{inst/extdata/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{image.png}
   \caption{captionA}
   \label{fig:labelA}
\end{figure}
```

I also tried like this, but this didn't work:

```
 \graphicspath{{filePath}}

 filePath = "C:/path"

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{image.png}
   \caption{captionA}
   \label{fig:labelA}
 \end{figure}
```

I have googled a lot, and look up https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Compiling_with_latex, but this is the error I get.

```
 LaTeX Warning: File `image.png' not found on input
 line 613.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `image.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.613 ...]{image.png}
```

Comment: is the image in the same folder where the .tex file is?

Comment: Just to clarify, the folder "inst/extdata" is inside my working directory. The .Rnw and .tex files are in working directory/vignette.     If someone could help me figure this out where i can give a relative path instead of absolute path, that would be very helpful

Comment: try to put the file to compile and the image to include in the same folder. LaTeX searches for picture to include in documents in the same directory where the file to be compiled is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So if I put everything inside the same folder, everything works. I am looking for a solution where the images and the .Rnw files are in  different folders.

Comment: Look at my answer; it offers three different ways of achieve your goal, two of them as perfect for your needs I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expand my comment with three different ways of achieve your goal; Suppose you want to include a file image named `IMG_7254.JPG` (note that I do not write the file extension in the following code because I use the `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.JPG}`), You can do it in three ways:

1. to put the file to compile (the *.tex* one) and the image to include in the same folder. LaTeX searches (**by default**) for pictures to include in documents in the same directory where the file to be compiled is. In this case the code is just:

   ```
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{IMG_7254}
   ```
2. Have pictures and file to compile in very different folders, in this case you must specify the complete path of the file (it can be found in different ways), example with Mac OS read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/371513/how-to-tell-full-path-of-file-on-mac). In this case the code is:

   ```
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{/Users/SabDeM/Pictures/IMG_7254}
   ```
3. to put the file to compile in a folder (say *File_to_com*), then put all pictures to include in a sub folder, say, *File_to_com/picturesToInc*, and then specify the path. In this latter case the code is:

   ```
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picturesToInc/IMG_7254}
   ```

As you can see in all ways (one way or another) LaTeX (which render the PDF) must to know where the pictures are located in your computer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response ! i am trying to do something like answer #2. But I cannot use absolute paths like   `{/Users/sabDeM/Pictures/IMG_7254}`. Is there a way to do something like this if I gave `{/Pictures/IMG_7254}` ? Thanks !

Comment: @kay impossible. LaTeX needs to know where to search the file to include. You must provide a complete path. Or you can choose option 1 or 3.

Comment: @kay Just for curiosity, why did you say that you "cannot use absolute paths" ? I do not see the reason underneath that.

Comment: I am trying to create an R package. It needs a "vignette" showing how to use the R package. So I cannot use absolute paths. I will have to put the image and the sweave files in the same folder. Thanks !

Comment: @kay read [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html). It is the new book by Hadley Wickham about R package development. It has this chapter about vignette, maybe you can find some (other) ideas or ways to do a vignette even though I think that with LaTeX, there are no way except the ones I suggested.

Comment: Thanks ! I have read this one. It may be okay afterall to put the image and the .Rnw in same "vignette" folder. Lets see.