# With knitr and LateX, how to avoid path above .png; and how to place two plots side-by-side in table

Tags: r, latex, png, knitr

New to LateX, I have two problems with it or knitr.  Running the code that follows the image of what is produced in PDF, there continue to appear three repetitions of the the path above the .png figure.

Second, the side-by-side table with a .png image in each is not appearing at all.

I would appreciate being corrected and educated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}

% \usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{graphicx}  % to import .png files
\usepackage{tabularx}  % note that there is no tabular package
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead{Survey Graphics}
\rhead{Pg. \thepage}
\cfoot{$\copyright$ lawyeR}

<<echo=FALSE, results="hide", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
lm_blue <- "#003767"
@

% \renewcommand
% \headrule{ 
% \color{lm_blue}
% \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
% \hrule width \hsize height 5pt 
% \end{minipage}}%
% 
% \newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\hfill \rule{0.2\linewidth}{#1}} % Horiz rule at bottom of page, adjust width here
% 
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}  
% \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}  

%% end preamble; begin document


\begin{document}

\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/blank/Documents/Marketing and Blog/ReproData Book Survey/Plots and images/} }

\begin{figure}[h]    
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width = 90mm, height = 2in]{C:/Users/blank/Documents/Marketing and Blog/ReproData Book Survey/Plots and images/Above the Law 2013 comment in plot.PNG}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


% lay out figures side-by-side using table

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
PNG One & PNG Two \\
\includegraphics[width = 20mm]{C:/Users/blank/Documents/Marketing and Blog/ReproData Book Survey/Plots and images/MLA Comp 2014 bars separated.PNG} &
\includegraphics[width = 20mm]{C:/Users/blank/Documents/Marketing and Blog/ReproData Book Survey/Plots and images/Winstonpg19noredundantdata2.PNG}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you specify `\graphicspath`, then don't include the paths inside `\includegraphics`. Also, since you have spaces in the names, you may need to add [`grffile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) to your preamble as well.

Comment: Excellent, and thank you.  I will try.  Any ideas about why the tabular code is not producing side-by-side pngs?

Comment: The PNGs might have a large white border around them.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663812/using-graphicspath-in-latex-sweave/31664152#31664152) answer of mine where I explained the different ways of find images without the `\graphicspath`.

Comment: @Werner: the grffile did the trick!  And your first suggestion.  If you want to put it in an answer I will accept it.  SabDeM: thank you for the informative link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With spaces in your filenames, you need to add

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

to your preamble. Additionally, once you've specified an appropriate set in `\graphicspath{..}`, you can remove all such path references in the `\includegraphics` commands.